# Exporting a portion of Oracle table

Tags: oracle, database-administration

I have a database having size more than 2.5 TB, now I need to remove data during a period and want to move to a tape. Its a financial data and now I have to keep only previous financial years data only. I don’t have space to keep the entire data base.

My requirement is to take the back up of the data of a particular duration and move in to a tape.

Thanking you in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can create partitionized table. Each partition have its own storage clause and thus it can be stored in different tablespaces - even on different media.
From an partitionized table you can easily export a single partion and drop it afterwards, if required.

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE(
  COL_A NUMBER,
  COL_DATE DATE)
TABLESPACE SMALL_DATA
PARTITION BY RANGE (COL_DATE)
(  
  PARTITION VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE(' 1900-01-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN')) TABLESPACE OLD_DATA,  
  PARTITION VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE(' 2013-04-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN')) TABLESPACE CURRENT_DATA
);
```

With package `DBMS_REDEFINITION` you can redefine an existing table to a partitionized table. Be aware that for redefinition you need twice the space which is used by your table.